# Symbol not found: _avpriv_ac3_channel_layout_tab

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

after having built a software that uses ffmpeg in a Mac, when I run the program I obtain the error:

**Symbol not found: _avpriv_ac3_channel_layout_tab**

referenced by libavformat.58.dylib etc

Which is the missing library? Is it a problem related to ffmpeg build from source?